# Add refresh button in Ext.TabPanel in Sencha touch

Tags: button, extjs, sencha-touch-2, refresh

how to add one more button (refresh button) in the same Ext.TabPanel. Mi code is here:

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.Twitter',{
  extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',
  xtype: 'twitter', 


   config: {
    title:'Twitter',
    iconCls: 'twitter2',

styleHtmlContent: true, 
items: [
    {
        title: 'Twitts',
        html: 'Lista de twitts'
    },
    {
        title: 'Mapa',
        html: 'Lugar de twitts'
    }
 ]
```

}
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
Ext.define('portofolio.view.Twitter',{
  extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',
  xtype: 'twitter', 


  config: {
    title:'Twitter',
    iconCls: 'twitter2',

    styleHtmlContent: true, 
   tabBar:{
            dockedItems:[{ 
                xtype: 'button',
                iconMask: true,
                dock: 'right',
                ui: 'action',
                stretch: false,
                style: 'height:35px;margin-top:5px;',
                handler: function(){
                    alert('Refresh panel');    
                }
            }]
        },
            items: [
                {
                    iconCls: 'refresh', 

                },
                {     
                    title: 'Twitts',
                    html: 'Aqui van los twitts'
                },
                {                  
                    title: 'Mapa',
                    html: 'Aqui encuntras el oro'
                }           
            ]
        },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add 1 more items to your `tab panel`:

```
items: [
    {
        title: 'Twitts',
        html: 'Lista de twitts'
    },
    {
        title: 'Mapa',
        html: 'Lugar de twitts'
    },
    {
        iconCls: 'refresh',
        title: 'Refresh',
        html: 'Refresh'
    }
]
```

Please note that if you're using version 2.0, you will not be able to see the icon image unless your `tabbar` docked at bottom. You should be fine if this is version 2.1

Comment: Thank you very much, but now i have one more tab named "Refresh". I want one button to refresh. Enough if I assign the function of refreshing? I am using version 2.1

Comment: I'm not really get what you mean. can you edit your question and elaborate more on you problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, by **refresh** button, you wanted to refresh the data being displayed inside `tabPanel`. You can use `toolbar` and set up different buttons that may be useful throughout the app. I've set up this working [fiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#x6RZV). It has `refresh` button on top-right corner.

Hope that helps. I'm also adding code here -

```
launch: function() {
        var view = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox'
            },
            items: [
                {

                    xtype:'toolbar',
                    docked:'top',
                    layout:{
                        type: 'vbox',
                        pack:'center',
                        align: 'right'
                    },
                    flex:1,
                    items:[
                        {
                            xtype:'button',
                            iconMask:true,
                            iconCls:'refresh',

                            handler:function(){
                                console.log('Refresh Button Tapped');
                                alert('Refresh Button Tapped');
                            }
                        }
                    ]

                },
                {
                    xtype:'panel',
                    layout:'fit',
                    flex:2,
                    items:[
                        {
                            xtype:'tabpanel',
                            tabBarPosition:'bottom',
                            defaults:{
                                styleHtmlContent:true
                            },
                            items:[
                                {
                                    title: 'Twitts',
                                    iconCls: 'home',
                                    html: 'Lista de twitts'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'Mapa',
                                    iconCls: 'maps',
                                    html: 'Lugar de twitts'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted if you find this useful. Will help others if they land on this question. :)